# Place title at the bottom of the figure of an axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

the title is moved vertically by `y` , yet if figheight changes the title is not at constant distance/padding to the xaxis:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,2.5*1.5))
axs.set_title("mytitle", fontsize=14, y=-0.2, ha='center')
```

[image]

so on increased figheight it moves away:

[image]

also i tried :
`axs.set_title("mytitle", fontsize=14, va='bottom', ha='center')` 
without re-location (stays at top) and the fontdict-form, no change:

`axs.set_title('my_title', fontdict={'fontsize': 20, 'verticalalignment': 'bottom', 'horizontalalignment': 'center'})`

**EDIT**

titles are just texts which i use instead now, its modular:

```
axs.text(0.5,1,'some_title', va='bottom', ha='center', transform=axs.transAxes, color='k', fontsize=15, bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'edgecolor':'white', 'alpha':1, 'pad':10})
```

more at [text cmds.](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/text_commands.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-text-commands-py)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the title at a specified distance in absolute coordinates from the xaxis. Hence you first position it at `y=0`. Then you can use some padding in units of points to shift it from there.

```
ax.set_title("Hello Title", y=0, pad=-25, verticalalignment="top")
```

You can use `constrained_layout=True` in the figure creation to have the title not be cropped when resizing.

A similar question about positioning the legend below the axes has been asked in [How to get constant distance between legend and axes even when the figure is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206575/how-to-get-constant-distance-between-legend-and-axes-even-when-the-figure-is-res)